# How to check if .net interoperability for excel is installed

Tags: .net, interop

I am using .net Primary Interoperability Assembly for Excel in my code.
But, the application can be run on machine which doesn't have .net PIA for Excel installed.
I want to give an error message if it is not installed

Even though I am checking in GAC, to see if PIA is installed and only if it is present I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel related code. I am getting an error.

My problem is - I am getting error which is - Unhandled Exception - can't find could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which version of Office are you targeting?

Comment: And what language are you developing in? C# or VB?

Comment: Make sure of the office version. The interop version for Office 2003 is 11.0 while for Office 2007 is 12.0.

Comment: I am targeting it for both version of Office i.e. 2K3 and 2K7 and I am using C#

Answer (score 1):

I've used this Building block to load the x86 / x64 versions of hunspell in may NHunspell wrapper. maybe it is a good starting point for your own dynamic loader:

```
            // Initialze the dynamic marshall Infrastructure to call the 32Bit (x86) or the 64Bit (x64) Dll respectively 
            SYSTEM_INFO info = new SYSTEM_INFO();
            GetSystemInfo( ref info );

            // Load the correct DLL according to the processor architecture
            switch( info.wProcessorArchitecture )
            {
                case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.Intel:
                    string pathx86 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    if (!pathx86.EndsWith("\\"))
                        pathx86 += "\\";
                    pathx86 +=  Resources.HunspellX86DllName;

                    dllHandle = LoadLibrary(pathx86);
                    if (dllHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new DllNotFoundException(string.Format(Resources.HunspellX86DllNotFoundMessage, pathx86));
                    break;

                case PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE.Amd64:
                    string pathx64 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
                    if (!pathx64.EndsWith("\\"))
                        pathx64 += "\\";
                    pathx64 += Resources.HunspellX64DllName;

                    dllHandle = LoadLibrary(pathx64);
                    if (dllHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                        throw new DllNotFoundException(string.Format(Resources.HunspellX64DllNotFoundMessage, pathx64));
                    break;
```

look at this delegate declarations:

```
internal delegate bool HunspellSpellDelegate(IntPtr handle, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string word);
```

And how to bind a library function to it

```
HunspellSpell = (HunspellSpellDelegate)GetDelegate("HunspellSpell", typeof(HunspellSpellDelegate));
```

I think this should work for you too, but you have to declare the complete interop code. You can check out the Nhunspell code to get a working sample of this technique:

[NHunspell Web Site](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

I guess System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application",true); method will throw exception if Excel is not present. You can use a try catch block and verify.

Comment: You probably would get `System.__ComObject` as the type if you don't have the interop installed. There is exception thrown.

Comment: Yes that is what the check is for.

Comment: Sorry, there was a 'no' missing in my comment. It should have read "There is **no** exception thrown."

Comment: My mistake. That was the wrong overload. Corrected it. Now this method call will throw exception if mentioned application is not installed.

Comment: Hello danish, Thanks for your reply.
I tried the method you suggested, but that doesnt work. If the machine where I run this program doesnt have PIA for excel installed then the it throws System.IO.FileNotFoundExceltion.

Comment: That is what the check is. Call the method. If you get exception, this means Excel is not installed so display a message or something. If it doesn't throws exception, carry on with the task.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't make static reference to Excel.Interop library. Instead of this, you should look for it in GAC, and load it in runtime. It's rather complicated, and there are no managed API to do this (by default).

Try to use this: [fusion.dll API wrapper](http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/articles/229649.aspx)