# How to check whether Primary Interop Assemblies are installed or not?

Tags: c#, .net, interop, pia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check if .net interoperability for excel is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237729/how-to-check-if-net-interoperability-for-excel-is-installed)

I am "using" Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in my C# code.

I want to use the code related to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel only if PIA for Excel is installed on that machine.

But, I get exception when I call that function (which uses Excel Interoperability)

Why am I getting exception even if that code actually isnt getting called? How to workaround this issue? i.e to use Excel PIA only if it is installed.

Thanks